# How Can I Display Task Colors in Kendo Schduler from Bound Resources

Tags: .net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am having trouble setting the background color for a task in Kendo Scheduler for dot net core UI. I have checked the several Stack Overflow questions on this topic but none of them supply the answer in my situation.
What is causing the colors I have set to not appear?

I bind resources to the scheduler and use a field for the text and value of the resource. This is "by the book" according to Telerik.

But when I run the scheduler, all the task cells are pinkish red. 
Where is it getting that color? It's not even one of the ones I chose!
There are no java script errors and all the tasks are the same color.

```
.Resources(resource =>
            {
                resource.Add(m => m.POCDiscipline)
                    .Title(@Localizer["Discipline"].Value)
                    .DataTextField("name")
                    .DataTextField("value")
                    .DataColorField("color")
                    .BindTo(new[] {
                        new { name = "Companion", value = "Companion", color = "#5D8AA8" },
                        new { name = "Homemaker", value = "Homemaker", color = "#87A96B" },
                        new { name = "Personal Care Attendant", value = "Personal Care Attendant", color = "#C32148" },
                        new { name = "Case Worker", value = "Case Worker", color = "#FFFF9F" }
                    });
                resource.Add(m => m.VisitEmployeeM.UserId)
                    .Name("Employees")
                    .Title("Employees")
                    .DataTextField("name")
                    .DataValueField("id")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetUserListByAgencyProvider", "DropDownList").Data("visitemployeevar"); });
                    });
            })
```

The name and value columns are the same, that is not a typo. The database field POCDiscipline has value shown such as "Companion."